# Inconsistent estimates from predictmeans

Tags: r, linear-regression

I recently heard about the **predictmeans** package in R, so I wanted to test it out. So I tried this test dataset and model:

```
data = data.frame(
    blk = LETTERS[rep(1:2, each = 4)],
    trt = letters[rep(1:4, each = 2)],
    x = c(3.3, 3.3, 1.8, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 5.4, 5.4),
    y = c(5.9, 5.8, 6.5, 6.7, 4.6, 4.5, 3.8, 3.8))
mod1 = lm(y ~ x + blk + trt, data = data)
```

Here are estimates of the `trt` means using `predictmeans::predictmeans` (output is severely abbreviated to show just the estimates):

```
library("predictmeans")
predictmeans(mod1, "trt")

## $`Predicted Means`
## trt
##      a      b      c      d 
## 5.0846 5.5462 5.0846 5.0846
```

It seems curious that three of the four means are equal. Even odder is that I get different results if I express the model differently:

```
mod2 = lm(y ~ blk + trt + x, data = data)
predictmeans(mod2, "trt")

## $`Predicted Means`
## trt
##     a     b     c     d 
## 4.825 5.575 5.575 4.825
```

Here we still have two different means, but the pattern is different. And it changes with yet a different model:

```
mod3 = lm(y ~ trt + blk + x, data = data)
predictmeans(mod3, "trt")

## $`Predicted Means`
## trt
##    a    b    c    d 
## 5.85 6.60 4.55 3.80
```

Now there are four different means!

The effect of setting the covariate `x` is different too. If we don't specify it, `predictmeans` will use `x = 3`; if I try `x = 0`, I get:

```
predictmeans(mod1, "trt", covariate = c(x = 0))

## $`Predicted Means`
## trt
##      a      b      c      d 
## 5.6615 6.1231 5.6615 5.6615

predictmeans(mod2, "trt", covariate = c(x = 0))

## $`Predicted Means`
## trt
##     a     b     c     d 
## 4.825 5.575 5.575 4.825
```

What I found is that specifying a different `x` value changes the results for `mod1`, but the results are identical for `mod2` regardless of `x` (this is true for `mod3` as well).

What is happening that produces such wildly inconsistent results? Is there a remedy for it?

Comment: Look at the output of mod1 directly.  Your design doesn't even allow you to estimate all of your parameters.

Comment: Hmmm. Shouldn’t it warn about that?